# JSON encoded with textual and code special characters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am using for encoding some text the php json_encode() function, and using  the jquery getJSON() for decoding.

It works great, but sometimes the text have textual and code chars like "this is a code char: %F1 and this is a textual one: ñ". The text should look as is, I mean that "%F1" should not appear as "ñ".

The json_encode() function returns a null value because of the "%F1" and if I use iconv() the "%F1" looks properly, but transform the "ñ" to "Ã±" and if I use mb_convert_encoding() it transforms the "%F1" to "?".

How can I normalize the text for a properly visualization?

**Update:**

There are some examples, the user should see the text "this is a code char: %F1 and this is a textual one: ñ". The $a variable contains the string "this is a code char: %F1 and this is a textual one: ñ" from the DB:

PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array("content" => $a));
```

In that case json_encode() returns null because the "%F1" (if I remove the %F1 the "ñ" char looks properly after getJSON())

Now using iconv():

PHP:

```
$a = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($a));
echo json_encode(array("content" => $a));
```

After the jquery getJSON() the user sees:
this is a code char: %F1 and this is a textual one: Ã±

And using mb_convert_encoding():

PHP:

```
$a = mb_convert_encoding($a, "UTF-8", "auto");
echo json_encode(array("content" => $a));
```

After the jquery getJSON() the user sees:
this is a code char: ? and this is a textual one: ñ

Comment: Can you please deliver some code examples and what you would expect, and what you are getting instead? It seems like you might wanna read up on general encoding/charsets/codepages things, and/or url-encoding though.

Comment: make sure you set the character encoding as utf-8 in your HTML, and that you save both HTML and PHP files as utf-8 encoded files.

Comment: Hi I update the question with some examples